# How to compile a linux kernel with SSE enabled?

Tags: compiler-errors, linux-kernel, sse, fpu

I am in the following situation:

1. I am adding a float point based algorithm to Linux kernel. I know I shouldn't do that, but I want to give it a try and see how bad it can be.
2. `kernel_fpu_begin/kernel_fpu_end` is used at every float point calculation blocks.
3. When I run `make` to compile the kernel code I get this error: `SSE register return with SSE disabled`, the corresponding line is `input[3] = (float)util / (float)max;`

Here are my questions:

1. I didn't find `-mno-sse -mno-sse2` in the Makefile, what can I do to enable the SSE?
2. When I declare some float point variables, for example, `float x[10]`, should I use `kernel_fpu_begin/kernel_fpu_end`?

Thanks!

Comment: *Some* questions could be valid even without the complete code. And I find out the current question to be one of them. (The question actually has *parts of code*, which are sufficient to understand the problem and resolve it). Voted for reopen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to stop the compiler from using SSE to e.g. copy a 16 byte struct before `kernel_fpu_begin` or after `end`.  So you can't just use a block inside a function in a file compiled with `-msse2`.

You might be able to put your FP code in a separate function and use [`__attribute__((target("sse2")))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Function-Attributes.html) or `"avx"` on that function, to enable it without command-line options, for x86 specifically.

Obviously that function can't *return* a `float` by value because the standard calling convention returns in XMM0, and you need the caller compiled without.