# what is SSE register, why I cant use float point in printk [error: SSE register return with SSE disabled 59 | printk("cl = [%f] --\n",*a);]

Tags: c, linux-kernel, floating-point

So I have this code that i am getting uint64_t from userspace and casting it to float pointer like this

```
    float *a=kmalloc(10,GFP_KERNEL);
    copy_from_user(a,(float *)&temp.a,10);
    
    printk("cl = [%f] [%f] --\n",a[0],*(a+1));
```

But I am getting error that

```
c:59:9: error: SSE register return with SSE disabled
   59 |         printk("cl = [%f] --\n",*a);
```

What is SSE do I need to disable it if it can be to run my simple code

My machine is x86-64 plus kernel 5.13

Comment: @BoP so does this mean I need to compile my kernel module with `-mgeneral-registers-only.` flag and use `kernel_fpu_begin` and `kernel_fpu_end`?

Comment: @BoP: That question involves the compiler choosing to use SSE registers for code that did not explicitly use floating-point. This question is about code that uses floating-point explicitly. They are not the same question.

Comment: I don't know what setting to use for a kernel module. Just that the kernel avoids using floating point in order to not have to save the users floating point state (which is quite large).

Comment: To perform floating-point operations in the Linux kernel, you have three choices: (0) Write integer code that manipulates the bits representing floating-point data. (1) Compile with support for software floating-point, so the compiler will generate such integer instructions and/or call library routines for it. (2) Call `kernel_fpu_begin` to enable floating-point in the kernel, then call a routine that does floating-point work, then call `kernel_fpu_end`. The floating-point routine must be in a separate source file compiled with switches to enable floating-point instructions.

Comment: @EricPostpischil what i found is kernel does not use floating point. but so why these functions available how to use these `kernel_fpu_begin` and `kernel_fpu_end`. do I need to compile my kernel with `-mgeneral-registers-only=false`

Comment: Those are the basics. I do not have specific instructions for doing this, as I do not work with Linux. This is general information to put you on the right track for investigation of the details.

Comment: @EricPostpischil `Write integer code that manipulates the bits representing floating-point data.` so u are saying I need to take all bits from my float data and copy it to in type and do operatings and then return back. Is that what u are saying

Comment: @user786: Do **not** compile your code with `-mgeneral-registers-only=false`. Any source file containing routines called by the kernel in its normal mode must be compiled with `-mgeneral-registers-only` enabled. The **only** way to call a routine that uses floating-point registers is to **first** call `kernel_fpu_begin`, then call a routine compiled in a separate translation unit, then call `kernel_fpu_end`. Once the routines are segregated into a separate translation unit, that unit can be compiled with `-mgeneral-registers-only=false`.

Comment: The reason you cannot simply compile with `-mgeneral-registers-only=false` is that GCC might use SSE for **any** part of the code in that source file, not just the code that explicitly uses floating-point. E.g, if you have `x = y;`, where `x` and `y` are, say, 16-byte structures, GCC might generate SSE instructions to copy `y` to `x`. With `-mgeneral-registers-only=false`, there is no way to guarantee that GCC does not generate SSE instructions before `kernel_fpu_begin` is called.

Comment: As a modification to (2), you may be able to put the code in a separate function, instead of an entirely separate translation unit, by using GCC’s `__attribute__` feature, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62125117/298225).

Comment: @user786: Yes, choice (0) is to use only integer code to work with the bits that represent floating-point data. Do not declare anything `float` or `double`, call floating-point library routines, or use floating-point constants.

Comment: @EricPostpischil `The only way to call a routine that uses floating-point registers is to first call kernel_fpu_begin,` does this mean I need to take out  my floating point code and code that in separate file and compile it with `make -mgeneral-registers-only=false` so I can call kernel_fpu_begin in that separate file where floating point work is done?

Comment: @EricPostpischil what my `__attribute__`  containg floating point function code only the line of attribute will look like?

Comment: @user786: Re “so I can call kernel_fpu_begin in that separate file where floating point work is done?”: **No.** You **cannot** enable floating-point code in the same file where `kernel_fpu_begin` is called (except by using function attributes as I mentioned previously). If you compile a module with GCC switches that allow floating-point code, then you cannot guarantee it does not perform any floating-point code is executed before `kernel_fpu_begin` is called. The call to `kernel_fpu_begin` must be in a clean module with no floating-point.

Comment: @EricPostpischil `then call a routine compiled in a separate translation unit` so I think what I understood is `kernel_fpu_begin` should be called in normal code and floating point code should be in separate function in separate file. and that separate function must have the attribute.  right and this separate file must be compiled with `registers-only=false`, is this right?